# How to check the original pod 's log after it restart in IBM Cloud?

Tags: kubernetes, logging, ibm-cloud, kubernetes-pod

I deploy one deployment on IBM Cloud which has one pod within it. I found the pod has already restart, But don't know the time point.

Can Anyone give any advice for checking the original pod log?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `kubectl logs --previous <pod-name>` command to view previous pod logs.

Comment: Since the pod name already changed after it was deleted and then restart or shut down. Is this command feasible? –